# Как сделать так, чтобы сумма случайных чисел была равна заданному числу?

Tags: excel, случайные-числа, vba

Есть некоторое число `x`. Оно находится в ячейке `B1`. Оно может принимать любые целочисленные значения.

Количество случайных чисел равно `y`. Оно задается вручную и находится в ячейке `B2`.

Задача в том, чтобы в столбце `С` получить `y` случайных чисел, сумма которых равна `х`

Все `х` принимают целочисленные значения.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: *в столбце С получить y случайных чисел* А каков допустимый диапазон этих случайных чисел? В общем - задача содержит два критерия, которые противоречат друг другу...

Answer (score 5):

В столбец `C` занести *y - 1* штук случайных целых из диапазона *[0, B<sub>1</sub>]*. Отсортировать по возрастанию. Приписать к ним значение *B<sub>1</sub>* в конце и ноль в начале. Рядом с отсортированным списком выписать последовательные разницы: *второе - первое*, затем *третье - второе*, и так далее до *B<sub>1</sub> - предпоследнее число в списке*.

Получится ряд действительно случайных чисел, сумма которых равна *B<sub>1</sub>*.

У меня нет Excel под рукой. Пример:

*B<sub>1</sub> = 100*, *y = 5*.

Случайные числа в диапазоне *[0, 100]*:

*44, 36, 81, 15*

Сортированный список, в который добавлены *0* и *B<sub>1</sub>*:

*0, 15, 36, 44, 81, 100*

Последовательные разницы:

*15, 21, 8, 37, 19*

Comment: @gpg, это не возможно. Y случайных чисел связаны условиями на сумму. Я могу лишь доказать что Y-1 случайных интервалов распеределены по Пуассону (кажется).

Comment: Понравилось решение ) Визуализировал (для отрицательных не делал), см. в файле *https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wAzs90w6tr7rF0doO02LCUOK3oJu1tcw/edit?usp=share_link&ouid=106706061277650382160&rtpof=true&sd=true*

Answer (score 0):

Условия лишь целочисленности и фиксированной суммы означает (как только y>1), что пространство элементарных событий бесконечно. Интуитивно понятного лидера среди всего разнообразия вероятностных пространств, которые можно определить на таком пространстве элементарных событий, нет. Если требуется только случайность в плане недетерминированности, то просто взять как угодно y-1 число из любого вероятностного пространства на целых цислах и добавить недостающее слагаемое до требуемой суммы. Если же требуется определённое распределение, то это надо сообщать в условии задачи.