# Как сгенерировать случайным образом числа, чтобы в сумме получалось определенное число?

Tags: python, алгоритм, случайные-числа

даны варианты ответа на задачу:

```
A) 1
B) 2
C) 3
D) 4
```

Нужно случайным образом сгенерировать числа(%), которые будут отображать вероятность, что это правильный ответ. В сумме должно получаться 100%

Например:

```
A) 12%
B) 6%
C) 48%
D) 34%
```

Comment: генерируете три числа, четвёртое получаете вычитанием. // более правильно генерировать второе, исходя из того, что осталось после генерации первого (и с третьим так же), но это уже высшая математика, квантовая физика, в общем, не забивайте себе голову.

Comment: Один из способов описан тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478213/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83/1478220#1478220

Comment: "даны варианты ответа" в данном случае интригует...

Comment: @Mbo, выглядит как подделка опроса? :)

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy Наверное, что-то подобное.

Comment: А мне пришла ассоциация из "кто хочет стать миллионером" - подсказка "помощь зала"))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сгенерировать *n - 1* случайное число, добавить к ним *0* и *100*. Отсортировать. Сосчитать разницы между соседями - это ответ.

> ```
> [21, 98, 24]          # случайные числа в интервале [0, 100]
> [21, 98, 24, 0, 100]  # добавлены края диапазона
> [0, 21, 24, 98, 100]  # после сортировки
> [ 21,  3, 74,  2   ]  # разности между соседями, их сумма равна 100
> ```

Код:

```
import random


n = 4
target = 100
samples = [random.randrange(target + 1) for _ in range(n - 1)] + [0, target]
samples.sort()
probs = [b - a for a, b in zip(samples[:-1], samples[1:])]
print(sum(probs), '=', ' + '.join(map(str, probs)))
```

> ```
> $ python random-percents.py
> 100 = 23 + 42 + 29 + 6
>
> $ python random-percents.py
> 100 = 4 + 49 + 20 + 27
>
> $ python random-percents.py
> 100 = 16 + 67 + 13 + 4
>
> $ python random-percents.py
> 100 = 13 + 9 + 23 + 55
> ```

Comment: P.S. Учесть, что ГСЧ может выдать 2 или даже 3+ одинаковых числа.

Comment: @Kromster, про распределение в задаче ни слова. Совпадающие вероятности приведут к нулевому проценту. И 100% тоже можно получить. ТС, если это проблема, обновите вопрос.